# Strip \t from beginning and end of Scrapy response

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to clean my Scrapy response. I'm buidling a simple price monitor but I'm having troubles getting clean price.

I get following response:

```
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t272.28€\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

Ideally, I would like it to be (in float?):

```
272.28
```

I'm using scrapy items to store values such as:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = HobbyItem()
    item['new_price'] = response.css('span.price.new-price').extract()
    item['base_price'] = response.css('span.price.base-price').extract()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what about `response.strip()`?

Comment: you can use regular expression to extract

Comment: I'm also in favor of regex here, because you have that `€` that you need to get rid of (assuming that the format is not consistent). If you know for sure that it will always be in that position, you can just remove the last character from the string.

Comment: It should be in same spot every time correct. Currency should be the same as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it seems like the text is in a list, so you first need to get the text out of the list and then strip it

```
>>> response = ['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t272.28€\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
>>> text = response[0]
'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t272.28€\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> clean_text = text.strip()
'272.28€'
>>> number_text = clean_text.replace("€", "")
'272.28'
>>> number = float(number_text)
272.28
```

Or as one-liner:

```
>>> response = ['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t272.28€\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
>>> float(response[0].strip().replace("€", ""))
272.28
```

Comment: Thanks that is the case. IT appears to be stored as a list. There are three different prices. What would you say it is the best way to escape errors when the list is out of range?

Comment: @MatijaŽiberna what do you mean with "out of range". The most pythotic way to escape errors is to use `try except`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
   item = HobbyItem()
   item['new_price'] = response.css('span.price.new-price::text').get().replace('€', '').strip()
   item['base_price'] = response.css('span.price.base-price::text').get().replace('€', '').strip()
```

Here get() method retrieves the first element matching the css and strip method strips the extra characters. You can know more in [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: I get the following error:
item['new_price'] = response.css('span.price.new-price::text').get().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: check if item is None, before applying strip method.

Answer (score 0):

After all the help this is the solution that worked for me (it is far from being most efficient)

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = HobbyItem()
    if response.css('span.price.new-price::text').extract():
        new_price = response.css('span.price.new-price::text').extract()
        new_price_clean = new_price[0]
        new_price_clean_strip = new_price_clean.strip()
        new_price_clean_euro = new_price_clean_strip.replace("€", "")
        final_new_price = float(new_price_clean_euro)
        item['new_price'] = final_new_price
    else:
        item['new_price'] = '0'
    if response.css('span.base-price::text').extract():
        new_price = response.css('span.base-price::text').extract()
        new_price_clean = new_price[0]
        new_price_clean_strip = new_price_clean.strip()
        new_price_clean_euro = new_price_clean_strip.replace("€", "")
        final_new_price = float(new_price_clean_euro)
        item['base_price'] = final_new_price
    else:
        item['base_price'] = '0'
    if response.css('span.price::text').extract():
        new_price = response.css('span.price::text').extract()
        new_price_clean = new_price[0]
        new_price_clean_strip = new_price_clean.strip()
        new_price_clean_euro = new_price_clean_strip.replace("€", "")
        final_new_price = float(new_price_clean_euro)
        item['price'] = final_new_price
    else:
        item['price'] = '0'
    item['name'] = response.css('h1>span::text').extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    yield item
```